# LINQ to SQL Classes & Datacontext are not created

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Afternoon all

This is driving me nuts.

For no apparent reason (of course there must be one), my web project will no longer generate LINQ to SQL classes/data contexts!!!

I am going about the usual routine of right clicking the project, adding new item, selected LINQ to SQL classes, then dragging over a table from Server Explorer, saving and build but no...the bloody thing won't appear!!!

Does anyone know why this might be happening/what have I done wrong?

Comment: Has `Custom Tool` property set to `MSLinqToSQLGenerator` for dbml file?

Comment: What version of VS are u running, is this a webforms or MVC project, please give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Basically, NEVER rename any items.

I had previously been using OnlineReporting in one item, the name space when linq creates the classes was using this as it's namespace.

However, I then later changed this to Reporting but when the linq to sql generation occurred, it was still using the 'old' namespace.

I went into the designer.cs file, amended the name space to match the new format and it worked.